# Control for setting no transaction limit on a webform

Tags: gui-design

[image]I am building a web form which collects information for a user. The administrator can set limits for a user which is the transaction limit for a user. 
What control will be intuitive for setting "no limits", when a user is set no transaction limits, the user can perform transaction with no upper limit. Right now, the number on the limit field is "0" which doesn't make sense from the user perspective.

UPDATED: So in the screenshot, there are different fields like Payment Entry limit, Daily trade limit. When there is a value in the field, that's the limit of that user. But when there is no value, the user limit is unlimited. I don't want leave it empty (when no limit). I need to show something different so that the user knows, there is no limit set

can someone help in putting a control on that page.

Comment: Hi Pradeep, are you able to provide a little more information as to what you have? Do you have any screenshots? At the moment, I'm not sure what information is visible to the user.

Comment: Hey Brett, I updated the question. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't necessarily think that it's a terrible idea to use '0' or an empty field to show that there is 'no limit', particularly if you make it clear to the user.

While it's perhaps not a common pattern, it's certainly not a new pattern or rare pattern. A quick google image search for 'set to 0 for no limit' will [show a few examples](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=set+to+0+for+no+limit&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwix55Sl35jUAhXLHZQKHXQ0B0UQ_AUICygC&biw=1920&bih=1076#imgrc=xBZAgTFupCMQ2M:&spf=1496186023578).

I see you're already using some help text in a bubble, so you could continue with that, or try something like the below:

[image]

If you're worried about users needing to input '0' multiple times and having a screen full of '0s', then you could try a message. Something like "Leave empty in order to set no limit", or "Limit only set if a value is entered", or "Defaults to 'no limit', if limit isn't set".

Comment: Thank you Brett. I appreciate it. I am going to use your idea (make use of the help bubble and empty field) and try to get some feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any evidence for how this might be received by the user but here's a suggestion: Allow the user to switch the limits on and off with a checkbox or some other mechanism.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFHCSe.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

That way users can simply turn off limits that they don't want.

I'm sure I've seem something like this in use somewhere but can't remember where.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Andrew. That certainly was an idea that I initially had. But will introduce a lot of checkbox which not only makes the UI look wacky but also a lot of clicks by the user which I want to avoid. Do you think I can tackle this with an alternate way?

Comment: If you want to avoid using '0' then you're going to need some sort of switch. You could solve the clicks problem with some scripting that automatically switches a field 'on' when the user adds a value. switching 'off' would still need to be a manual event.

Comment: Thank you Andrew, I am going to try both Brett and your idea and try to get some feedback from other around here.

Comment: That sounds like a good approach! :D

Comment: You could, perhaps, have the check-box to the left of the field (with no label; just using the label above both the checkbox and input field: `[x] [10,000]` vs. `[.] [greyed]` (and a "tick" for the `x`).